# Какое дополнительное ПО вы используете в программировании?

Tags: java, c++, c

То есть какие программы вы используете? Будь то IDE или UML редакторы или svn менеджеры. В общем все что так или иначе помогает вам затрачивать меньше времени на разработку или достигать лучшего понимания.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вообще всё это очень сильно зависит а) от языка (языков), на котором пишет программист (вместе с сопутствующими технологиями, будь то фреймворки, библиотеки и прочее) б) от задач, которыми программист занимается. Поэтому разнообразие (а главное полезность) ответов может быть очень обширным. Вряд ли Android-разработчик на Java пользуется теми же инструментами, что и человек, пишущий что-то низкоуровневое на Си

Скажу за себя

**Основное:**

1. IDE - VS 2012
2. Система контроля версий - Mercurial (TortoiseHg) (раньше использовал TFS, но выбор той или иной системы для меня обусловлен желанием работодателя)
3. SQL Management Studio

**Плагины:**

1. ReSharper - кто пишет на C# и знает, что это, те, думаю, поймут, кто пишет, но не знает - непременно узнайте, и вы тотчас же попадёте в мир, где пони кушают радугу и какают бабочками
2. VisualHG - удобный плагин для VS, позволяющий работать с Mercurial прямо из студии
3. NuGet - пакетный менеджер, думаю, все, кто работает с Visual Studio, о нем знают
4. SQL Assistant - прикручивает человеческий Intellisense для SQL Management Studio
5. Для отладки JS использую FireBug (хотя основным браузером для меня является Google Chrome)

**Разная полезная чепуха, не относящаяся к программированию:**

1. Total Commander. До сих пор не очень понимаю, почему им мало кто пользуется из моих знакомых, предпочитая бесконечно огромный функционал проводника Windows
2. Notepad++
3. STDU Viewer - наверное, не самый лучший, но целиком устраивающий меня просмотрщик pdf, djvu и тому подобного. С него удобно читать техническую литературу
4. Punto Switcher - как ни странно, очень даже удобен для программиста. Нужно лишь внести в его список исключений программы, в которых пишете код
5. XMLPad - это просто XML-редактор, к которому у меня довольно скромные требования
6. Skype

**Веб-сервисы**

1. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) - классика жанра
2. [Вот довольно неплохой сервис](http://www.compileonline.com/) - обычно пользуюсь им, если нужно быстро посмотреть выполнение куска кода. Сервис не без недостатков, но подкупает большое количество поддерживаемых языков
3. [И еще один](https://compilr.com/) - похож на предыдущий, но функционал получше. Однако требует регистрации
4. [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) - об этом сервисе узнал здесь, на Хэшкоде. Способен преобразовывать С++-опусы в asm с выбором из нескольких компиляторов. В принципе в работе мне он не слишком нужен, но вообще штука любопытная, авось кому пригодится

**Кое-что ещё**

1. CodeBlocks - если нужно написать/посмотреть/отладить какой-нибудь HelloWorld на С++. Думаю, для студента эта среда очень даже хороша
2. GitHub-клиент

Ну а еще тут может быть еще куча разных инструментов, варьирующихся в зависимости от решаемых задач

Comment: А ideone? Как  по мне, так по удобнее http://www.compileonline.com/ будет

Comment: >А ideone? Как по мне, так по удобнее

@danpetruk возможно, это у меня просто [синдром утёнка][1]

[1]:http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%83%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 6):

1. Я обычно использую как минимум 2 разных IDE. У каждого IDE всегда есть свои сильные и слабые стороны.
2. Не гнушаюсь сторонними сборщиками вроде ANT, в последнее время пробую хваленый [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org) - но как то пока не впечатлил
3. Под рукой всегда должен быть какой-нибудь SQL браузер/менеджер. Редко когда при программировании обходится без БД. Инструмент обычно зависит от собственно самой БД, иногда хватает встроенного в IDE SQL инструментария, иногда приходится использовать что-нибудь тяжелое вроде MS SQL Server Management Studio или Oracle SQL Developer
4. Далее по списку проходит бинарный вьюер/редактор типа HexEditor - редко но бывает нужен
5. TeamViewer также must have - незаменим при командной разработке. Иногда проще показать чем долго и нудно объяснять
6. Skype - без него никуда.
7. Ну про SVN/Git/CVS умолчу - это и так ясно. Единственное уточнение - не использую всякие надстройки над VCS'ами типа SubCommander/Tortoise и проч. навороты.

Comment: тоже самое, правда для девелопмента с субд использую toad, лучше инструмента пока не видел. правда не фри, к сожалению фришный плагин для eclipse ужасно убог

Answer (score 5):

Вы задали добрый вопрос))

**[[@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild)** прав, что всё сильно зависит от языков программирования / платформ и т.п, поэтому я отвечаю за своё:

Мои основные ОС это Gentoo Linux и Mac OS X, а языки главным образом Objective-C и Ruby.

Итак, по порядку:

**Текстовый редактор, IDE**

Для iOS-разработки IDE - это, конечно, Xcode, а для Ruby и вообще для работы в Linux терминале - это всегда vim с дефолтной конфигурацией [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus).

**Терминал**

Кроме того, что может быть сделано только в `Xcode`, всё остальное я предпочитаю делать через командную строку - даже некоторые процедуры которые доступны в Xcode (см., например, `rake clean` ниже). Для этого как в Linux, так и в Mac OS X я использую терминалы, которые выпадают/скрываются по клавише F12. Это так называемые Quake-консоли. Для Gentoo - это `rxvt-unicode`, для Mac OS X - это `iTerm2`.

**Системы контроля версий - Git, Mercurial**

Всё руками кроме просмотра диффов с помощью [Tortoise для Mac OS X](https://bitbucket.org/skrysmanski/thg-mac-app).

Единственное расширение, которое я использую для Mercurial - это [purge](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension) - он нужен для быстрой очистки дерева (в git его аналог git clean -f -d): hg update --clean && hg purge.

**Command-line tools**

Я очень интенсивно использую rake и make. Каждый мой проект, как правило имеет в своём корне Makefile или Rakefile (последнее время для Objective-C проектов мне как-то больше полюбился именно make). Вот перечень задач, которые есть почти во всех проектах:

1. Прогон юнит-тестов с помощью rake/make test. На Ruby - make test вызывает `rspec spec/`, На Mac OS - это сборка и прогон unit-test target'а iOS-приложения с помощью xcodebuild (некоторые проекты вручную с помощью clang).
2. Развёртывание iOS-приложений на TestFlight. Для этого я использую [shenzhen](https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen) из пакета [Nomad](http://nomad-cli.com/) - в нём есть ещё несколько замечательных утилит, но ими пока воспользоваться не пришлось.
3. Для iOS-проектов последнее время я неизменно использую специальный rake-таск - `rake clean`. Он делает полную очистку Xcode-проекта - удаляет все версии приложения по всех версиях симулятора из папки `~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/`, удаляет `Derived Data`, связанное с данным приложением. Кто занят Mac- или iOS-разработкой - попробуйте! Незаменимо!

---

Пока всё. Обновлю ответ, если вдруг что забыл.

Comment: Познавательно в тему как работают iOS девелоперы

Answer (score 3):

Total Commander (с парочкой плагинов), Hg/TortoiseHg, SciTe-Ru.

Comment: надеюсь, не в Тотал Коммандере программируете?

Comment: @DreamChild, в какой-то степени да - использую в качестве IDE.

Comment: @insolor а где это может быть нужно? Разве не удобнее пользоваться именно IDE? Помнится, я пользовался Тоталом в подобных целях когда делал лабораторные по ассемблеру - у меня были только компилятор и компоновщик, и работать с ними через его командную строку было несколько удобнее

Comment: @DreamChild, для больших проектов на Си/С++ конечно лучше подойдет "нормальная" IDE.

При реверс инженеринге часто приходится перетаскивать файл в "большой" дизассемблер, в "маленький" дизассемблер, в отладчик, в хекс-редактор, и иногда что-то в текстовом редакторе быстро набрать, [s]кинуть папку с музыкой в плеер[/s] и при этом не хочется ждать пока какая-нибудь монстроподобная IDE загрузится (достаточно уже того что "большой" дизассемблер сам по себе монстроподобен).

Для программ на скриптовых языках связки простого текстового редактора + Тотал + SCM также вполне достаточно.

Comment: *Дополнение имен после @ рулит*

Answer (score 3):

0.JVM (без неё java код не запустится :)

1. intellj idea
2. dropbox (компов то несколько...)
3. [Cloud9](http://c9.io) Как по мне, так всякие webstorm слишком тяжелы для web-dev. А этот в самый раз
4. JSfidlle
5. http://ideone.com (когда нужно поделится не js кодом)
6. Sand ide - позволяет кодить и запускать java приложения на android. Особым умом не блещет, однако для олимп. задач хватает
7. Geany - какие-нибудь xml-ки поправить
8. Chrome web tools

Answer (score 3):

**Среды разработки:**

- [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)
- [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

**Базы данных:**

- [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)
- [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

**Текстовые редакторы:**

- [TextMate](http://macromates.com)
- [TextWrangler](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/textwrangler/id404010395)

**Контроль версий:**

- [GitHub](http://mac.github.com)

**Построение UML диаграмм:**

- [Diagrammix](http://deepit.ru/ru/products/Diagrammix/info/)